# Python: find all urls which contain string

Tags: python, url

I am trying to find all pages that contain a certain string in the name, on a certain domain. For example:

```
www.example.com/section/subsection/406751371-some-string 
www.example.com/section/subsection/235824297-some-string 
www.example.com/section/subsection/146783214-some-string
```

What would be the best way to do it?

The numbers before "-some-string" can be any 9-digit number. I can write a script that loops through all possible 9-digit numbers and tries to access the resulting url, but I keep thinking that there should be a more efficient way to do this, especially since I know that overall there are only about 1000 possible pages that end with that string.

Comment: Iterate through the urls and on each url check: `url.endswith('-some-string')`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye It sounds like he might not have an explicit list to iterate over

Comment: Do you have a pyhton script already or you have just a single text file?

Comment: No, there is no list of specific urls anywhere on the website. I did think about looking for them on google (and then extracting them from the search results). But is there a better way?

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia I don't have a script I'm not even sure if what I need is to build a crawler (or maybe not?). I have scraped websites before (using scrapy) but I had either a list of urls or a starting url. Now I don't have the list of urls, I know that they exist, but unless I go through all possible combinations of numbers I don't know how to find the actual urls.

Comment: Have you considered to then put all of the urls  _into_ a list then iterate through them that way?

Comment: @MattR : I don't know what the urls are. I only know that the urls are of the form: www.example.com/section/subsection/XXXXXXXXX-some-string, where X are random digits.

Comment: What about creating all the possible combination of numbers and test if it is a valid url?

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia : I was hoping there's a better way to do it.

Comment: I wouldn't put all 9 digit combination in a list just to test. Brute force works, but do you really want to do that? Let's look at it at a human stand point. The website obviously doesn't expect humans to remember 9 random generated numbers, so there must be something else that allows you to get to that section of site. Is it a link (which scrappy or BS4 would sniff out pretty easy) or is it like an entry generated form. If it's the latter there must be something special on that site for it to be randomly generated so why look at all the combinations instead of just ghostly generating the ones

Comment: BeautifulSoup and re.compile the pattern, if they can be isolated with the ending string you can use a CSS selector href$=-some-string

Answer (score 0):

I understood your situation, the numeric value before -some-string is a kind of object id for that web site (for example, this question has a id 39594926, and the url is stackoverflow.com/questions/**39594926**/python-find-all-urls-which-contain-string)

I don't think there is a way to find all valid numbers, unless you have a listing (or parent) page from that website lists all these numbers. Take Stackoverflow as an example again, in the question list page, you will see all these question ids.

If you can provide me the website, I could have a look try to find the 'pattern' of these numbers. For some simple website, that number is just a increment to identify objects (could be user, question or anything else).

Comment: Thanks, but there really is no pattern. This is a news website. Each week they publish a random number of articles. Every new article gets the next available number. Each week they publish one which ends with "-some-string", so the numbers assigned to these articles can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

If these articles are all linked to on one page you could parse the html of this index page since all links will be contained in the href tags.